# Encryption in ASP.net Core and Decryption in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am facing problems in "Encryption in ASP.net Core and Decryption in Angular".
I want to send sensitive information to FE from my BE so I am trying to add encryption and decryption.

My ASP code for encryption is :

```
public static string EncryptString(string key, string plainText)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] array;

            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.IV = iv;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                        }

                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
        }
```

And my Angular Code for Decryption is: (Using crypto-js for decryption)

```
decryptData(data,key) {

    try {
      const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key); //data is encrypted string from ASP
      if (bytes.toString()) {
        return JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
      }
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

After running the code I am getting errors like :

Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
at Object.stringify (core.js:513)
at WordArray.init.toString (core.js:268)
at ...

Thank you.

Comment: You know about https right..?

Comment: @MikeOne I know a little bit about it, but In this case, I want to hide that data in my browser's network tab so I am encrypting it.

Comment: Your ASP code is using AES in mode CBC that involves an initialization vector ('iv'). On Angular the same iv has to be used for decryption but I do not see any 'iv' ?

Comment: @MichaelFehr I had added IV in my code but still, the error was the same so I removed it. CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { 
      iv: iv, 
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C# code uses AES in CBC mode with a zero vector as IV and PKCS7 padding. The ciphertext is Base64 encoded. With the following sample data the following Base64 encoded ciphertext results:

```
string key = "01234567890123456789012345678901"; // 32 bytes key, corresponds to AES-256
string plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string encrypted = EncryptString(key, plaintext);
Console.WriteLine(encrypted); // NsFJlGQScUEazmSEykVeO/lh+o2L5ykFd2hkNa5lVrHACwKfTg1pD/uYzjTfjmQO
```

CryptoJS uses for AES the CBC mode and PKCS7 padding by default. It is important that the key in `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` is passed as `WordArray`, otherwise it will be interpreted as password from which the key is first derived. The Base64 encoded ciphertext can be passed directly. `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` returns a `WordArray` that must be decoded with Utf8. For the conversion from and to `WordArray`s CryptoJS has encoders. The following CryptoJS code allows the decryption:

```js
function decryptData(key, ciphertextB64) {                              // Base64 encoded ciphertext, 32 bytes string as key
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);                             // Convert into WordArray (using Utf8)
    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);   // Use zero vector as IV
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextB64, key, {iv: iv}); // By default: CBC, PKCS7 
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);                       // Convert into string (using Utf8)
}
    
var ciphertextB64 = "NsFJlGQScUEazmSEykVeO/lh+o2L5ykFd2hkNa5lVrHACwKfTg1pD/uYzjTfjmQO";
var key = "01234567890123456789012345678901";
var decrypted = decryptData(key, ciphertextB64);
console.log(decrypted); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Note that using a static IV (e.g. zero vector) is generally insecure. Usually, the IV is randomly generated during encryption and is passed to the recipient together with the ciphertext.

Comment: Thank You so much. This code worked perfectly. I spent too much time on this problem. Thank you for clearing concepts! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update on this as it's a few years old (but still very helpful!) I've made one small change to @Topaco. CryptoJS doesn't use .create, so instead you need init a new WordArray().

```
decryptString(key: string, ciphertextB64: string) {                              
    // Base64 encoded ciphertext, 32 bytes string as key
    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);                      // Convert into WordArray (using Utf8)
    var iv = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);    // Use zero vector as IV
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextB64, keyBytes, { iv: iv }); // By default: CBC, PKCS7 
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);                       // Convert into string (using Utf8)
```

}

Comment: *...CryptoJS doesn't use .create, so instead you need init a new WordArray()...* This is not true in this generality! `create()` **is supported** as you can verify with the executable code in the other answer for v4.0.0 (or here https://jsfiddle.net/L8gb5z92/ for the latest version v4.1.1) and in the [source code](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/4.1.1/core.js#L251). That it doesn't work for you is probably an environment specific (angular?) issue.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Topaco... you are correct .... I AM using the TS version (npm crypto-ts) and I think the TS version is slightly different and that's why I wasn't seeing it!